# ERROR: No FxCop analysis has been performed on this project, whereas it contains cs files

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

**SonarQube version 6.1**

One of our Sonar Analysis for MSBuild is failling with below errors, can you please check.

```
20-Dec-2016 07:20:41    ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
20-Dec-2016 07:20:41    ERROR: No FxCop analysis has been performed on this project, whereas it contains cs files: Verify that you are using the latest version of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, and if you do, please report a bug. In the short term, you can disable all FxCop rules from your quality profile to get rid of this error.

20-Dec-2016 07:20:41    ERROR:
20-Dec-2016 07:20:41    ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Scanner with the -e switch.
20-Dec-2016 07:20:41    ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

**UPDATE:**

I recently installed latest C# plugin, I am now getting access denied errors ,

06-Jan-2017 06:30:59          ERROR: Failed to analyze the file: D:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\EP-AR-JOB1\Quintiles.Sitecore.ePatient.Arcalyst\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs

06-Jan-2017 06:30:59          ERROR: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\EP-AR-JOB1\Quintiles.Sitecore.ePatient.Arcalyst\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs' is denied.

06-Jan-2017 06:30:59          ERROR:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

06-Jan-2017 06:30:59          ERROR:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

06-Jan-2017 06:30:59         ERROR:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

06-Jan-2017 06:30:59         ERROR:    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.CompilationHelper.GetSolutionFromFiles(String filePath, Encoding encoding, AnalyzerLanguage language)

06-Jan-2017 06:30:59         ERROR:    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.Program.RunAnalysis(ScannerAnalyzerConfiguration conf)

Comment: Ok: did you use the latest version of the SonarQube Scanner?

Comment: I have installed the latest version of scanner 'sonar-scanner-2.8'

Comment: 'D:\Program Files\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\sonar-scanner-2.8'